# How to find Multi variables using GA in matlab?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

Here is my model:

[image]

Solving this problem, I used GA in matlab

```
function F = sim_fit(q,k,m)
%retailer
a(1,1)=3;a(2,1)=2;a(3,1)=3;a(1,2)=1;a(2,2)=1.1;a(3,2)=9;
d(1,1)=1850;d(2,1)=2000;d(3,1)=3000;d(1,2)=2100;d(2,2)=1300;d(3,2)=900;
hr(1,1)=2.4;hr(2,1)=1.3;hr(3,1)=38;hr(1,2)=4.5;hr(2,2)=3.6;hr(3,2)=45;
so(1,1)=3.5;so(2,1)=1.5;so(3,1)=2.5;so(1,2)=0.3;so(2,2)=0.6;so(3,2)=6.3;
t(1,1)=1;t(2,1)=1;t(3,1)=3;t(1,2)=1;t(2,2)=1;t(3,2)=3;
E(1,1)=2;E(2,1)=2;E(3,1)=10;E(1,2)=2;E(2,2)=2;E(3,2)=10;
Y(1,1)=3;Y(2,1)=3;Y(3,1)=11;Y(1,2)=3;Y(2,2)=3;Y(3,2)=11;

%vendor
S=100;
hv(1)=3.5;hv(2)=4;
C(1)=10; C(2)=50;
Cv(1)=2.4; Cv(2)=3;
Cf(1)=3; Cf(2)=1.2;
s(1)=0.3; s(2)=0.1;
the(1)=0.01; the(2)=0.03;
dv(1)=sum(d(1,1)+d(1,2));dv(2)=sum(d(2,1)+d(2,2));
Q(1)=sum(q(1,1)+q(1,2));Q(2)=sum(q(2,1)+q(2,2));
P(1)=10000; P(2)=8000;


%function
for j=1:2
 for i=1:2   
F= S*dv(i)/(Q(i)*m(i,j))+(hv(i)*Q(i)*((m(i)-1)*(1-dv(i)/P(i))+dv(i)/P(i)))/2+...
dv(i)*(m(i)*C(i)+m(i)*Q(i)*Cv(i)+Cf(i))+m(i)*s(i)*dv(i)*Q(i)*the(i)/2+...
a(i,j).*d(i,j)./q(i,j)+(hr(i,j).*((1-k(i,j)).^2).*q(i,j))./2+...
k(i,j).^2.*so(i,j).*q(i,j)./2+(m(i)*t(i,j).*d(i,j))./q(i,j)+(m(i)*E(i,j).*d(i,j))./q(i,j)+...
Y(i,j).*d(i,j);
 end
end
end


function [C, ceq] = sim_constraint(q,k,m)
B(:,1)=200;B(:,2)=300;
W(:,1)=100;W(:,2)=100;
b(1)=10; b(2)=14;
w(1)=1; w(2)=1.5;
P(1)=10000; P(2)=8000;
C=[(m(1).*q(1,1).*b(1)+m(2).*q(2,1).*b(2))-B(:,1);
    (m(1).*q(1,2).*b(1)+m(2).*q(2,2).*b(2))-B(:,2);
  (m(1).*q(1,1).*w(1)+m(2).*q(2,1).*w(2))-W(:,1);
    (m(1).*q(1,2).*w(1)+m(2).*q(2,2).*w(2))-W(:,2);
    m(1)*Q(1)-P(1);m(2)*Q(2)-P(2)
    k(1,1)-1;k(1,2)-1;k(2,1)-1;k(2,2)-1];
ceq=[d(1,1)+d(1,2)-dv(1);(d(2,1)+d(2,2))-dv(2);
(q(1,1)+q(1,2))-Q(1);(q(2,1)+q(2,2))-Q(2)];
end
```

First, I don't know how to input Xij which is binary variable in sim_fitness function.

Second, in order to solve this problem, I use Optimization Toolbox.
Error message said "need more input variable."

How can I fix it?

Comment: How exactly did you use Optimization Toolbox? Which line generated the error? Also, your MATLAB version sounds suspiciously alike the little robot from "Short Circuit" :-)

Comment: Whoah, yeah, soooo many indices!

Comment: I'm missing the definition of `Q`, `d` and `dv` from your last function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question. But please, *please* start using matlab as it was intended:) If it was this cumbersome, then people would not be using it.

The net happiness of the human race will increase if you change your existing code to something like this:

```
function F = sim_fit(q,k,m)
   %retailer
   a=[3 2 3; 1 1.1 9].'; %or a=[3 1; 2 1.1; 3 9];
   d=[1850 2000 3000; 2100 1300 900].';
   hr=[2.4 1.3 38; 4.5 3.6 45].';
   so=[3.5 1.5 2.5; 0.3 0.6 6.3].';
   t=[1 1 3; 1 1 3].';
   E=[2 2 10; 2 2 10].';
   Y=[3 3 11; 3 3 11].';

   %vendor
   S=100;
   hv=[3.5 4];
   C=[10 50];
   Cv=[2.4 3];
   Cf=[3 1.2];
   s=[0.3 0.1];
   the=[0.01 0.03];
   dv=sum(d(1:2,:),2).'; %row vector like the earlier ones
   Q=sum(q(1:2,:),2).';
   P=[10000 8000];


   %function
   for j=1:2
      for i=1:2   
         F= S*dv(i)/(Q(i)*m(i,j))+(hv(i)*Q(i)*((m(i)-1)*(1-dv(i)/P(i))+dv(i)/P(i)))/2+...
            dv(i)*(m(i)*C(i)+m(i)*Q(i)*Cv(i)+Cf(i))+m(i)*s(i)*dv(i)*Q(i)*the(i)/2+...
            a(i,j).*d(i,j)./q(i,j)+(hr(i,j).*((1-k(i,j)).^2).*q(i,j))./2+...
            k(i,j).^2.*so(i,j).*q(i,j)./2+(m(i)*t(i,j).*d(i,j))./q(i,j)+(m(i)*E(i,j).*d(i,j))./q(i,j)+...
            Y(i,j).*d(i,j);
      end
   end

end


function [C, ceq] = sim_constraint(q,k,m)
   B=[200 300];
   W=[100 100];
   b=[10 14];
   w=[1 1.5];
   P=[10000 8000];

   mtmp=reshape(m(1:2),1,[]); %since I don't know its size, be on the safe side
   qtmp=q(1:2,1:2); %same thing here

   %WHAT IS Q?
   %WHAT IS d?
   %WHAT IS dv?

   C=[((mtmp.*b)*qtmp - B).';
      ((mtmp.*w)*qtmp - W).';
      (mtmp.*Q-P).'; %assuming Q is of size [1, 2]
      reshape(k(1:2,1:2).',4,1)-1];

   ceq=[sum(d(1:2,1:2),2)-dv.';
        sum(q(1:2,1:2),2)-Q.']; %assuming Q is of size [1, 2]

end
```

Sorry, I didn't have it in me to decrypt your expression for `F`. I strongly suggest getting familiar with the basic array syntax of matlab, and checking for yourself whether I made any mistakes during the conversion of your code. If you learn how to work with matrices and vectors, expressions like what you have for `F` can be radically simplified.

Also, the definition of the variables `Q`, `d` and `dv` seem to be missing from your second function. Those aren't `global`s, are they?